# What's the origin of "if it's worth writing, it's worth rewriting"?

Tags: expressions, origin-unknown, phrase-origin

I'm sure someone famous and wise once said, about writing either prose or software source code, that:

> If it's worth writing, it's worth re-writing.

meaning that one shouldn't avoid going ahead and writing something just because it is likely to be imperfect, or not future proof - since we should not try to avoid having to rewrite it in the future as things change.

Who was it? Or - where might I have picked this phrase up?

Comment: I've never heard the expression before, it might be a paraphrase of: *if it is worth doing, it's worth doing well*- http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/if-it-a-thing-is-worth-doing-it-s-worth-doing-well

Comment: @Josh: But it's a bit like the opposite of the phrase you quoted. That is, if it's worth doing, it's worth doing not-so-well at first.

Comment: I am referring to the structure of the expression..if it is worth...,it is worth.... not the meaning. I can't find usage examples of your sentence.

Comment: `if it's worth doing, it's worth doing not-so-well at first` Nah- both mean the same thing. Both are essentially saying "before you consider something a finished product, make sure it's good". The part about rewriting is just acknowledging that the first draft of anything is shit.

Comment: The essence of the saying "if it's worth writing, it's worth rewriting" is that it [the thing being written] can't be written well on a first draft. Or in other words, "if it's to be written well, it must be rewritten—and if it's not to be written well, why are you writing it at all?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because identification of the authors of quotations is not within the remit of EL&U. Perhaps some site dealing in English Literature might be able to help.

Comment: I don't agree that questions about expressions that seem to inhabit the borderlands of proverbs, idioms, or other familiar expressions are (or should be) off-topic. The poster of this question, for example, acknowledges that he or she "might have picked this phrase up" from the commons of everyday speech, despite thinking it more likely to have been someone's famous saying. I find questions of this sort interesting to research and enjoyable to answer—certainly more so than the dozens of single-word requests that this site receives monthly.

Answer (score 1):

There are various forms of the expression you ask about. The earliest nearly exact match I could find in a Google Books search is from Paul Attewell, [*Radical Political Economy Since the Sixties: A Sociology of Knowledge Analysis*](https://books.google.com/books?id=cMFdAAAAIAAJ&q=%22worth+writing%22+%22worth+rewriting%22&dq=%22worth+writing%22+%22worth+rewriting%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn15vH4-7VAhVLslQKHTyYBwgQ6AEILDAB) (1984) [combined snippets]:

> My wife and colleague, Katherine Newman, was involved in every stage of producing this manuscript, offering substantive criticisms, improving my grammar, and convincing me that **if a book is worth writing, it is worth rewriting**. I am greatly in her debt.

But a similar idea is at work in Richard Hefler, [*Creative Preaching and Oral Writing*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sP7jOj3XjlgC&pg=PA152&dq=%22worth+writing%22+rewriting&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu6c7n4u7VAhWFsVQKHTLtCzEQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22worth%20writing%22%20rewriting&f=false) (1978):

> It is often said that anything worth doing is worth doing well. It should follow in the art of sermon preparation that **anything worth writing is worth revising**. Rewriting takes time.

And earlier still is this excerpt from National Education Association of the United States, [*Addresses and Proceedings*](https://books.google.com/books?id=wCIWAAAAIAAJ&q=%22An+article+that+is+worth+printing+is%22&dq=%22An+article+that+is+worth+printing+is%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo99KF6e7VAhXjx1QKHW7YCsoQ6AEINTAD), volume 63 (1925), describing the job of editing the journal of an education association:

> Eight controlling ideas may well govern the work of its editor. They are:
>
> 1. The journal should be edited first, last, and all the time in the interests of the reader.
> 2. **An article that is worth printing is worth rewriting** to meet readers' needs.

As Hefler (and commenter Josh above) suggests, the familiar adage that the writing-and-rewriting advice ultimately draws on is "anything worth doing is worth doing well." That expression is widely credited to Lord Chesterfield, who expounded it in a [letter to his son](https://books.google.com/books?id=83MMAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA40&dq=%22in+truth+whatever+is+worth+doing+at+all+is+worth+doing+well%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1gKXq5u7VAhXkjVQKHSxWDQAQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22in%20truth%20whatever%20is%20worth%20doing%20at%20all%20is%20worth%20doing%20well%22&f=false) dated October 9, 1746:

> If care and application are necessary to the acquiring of those qualifications [namely, "speaking and writing clearly, correctly, and with ease and grace"], without which you can never be considerable, nor make a figure in the world ; they are not less necessary with regard to the lesser accomplishments, which are requisite to make you agreeable and pleasing in society. In truth, **whatever is worth doing at all is worth doing well** ; and nothing can be done well without attention : I therefore carry the necessity of attention down to the lowest things, even to dancing and dress.

Still, I would be very surprised if generations of ancient Sumerians did not say the same thing to their children.